# Cordova Android Crash Backtrace

Tags: android, cordova, crash, backtrace

I have a high number of crashes in the Android version of a Cordova app. Due to limited experience with Android, I have found the following line a common similarity in backtraces:

pc 0000000001053a38 /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.print.PrintManager.removePrintJobStateChangeListener+200)

I'm using the cordova-plugin-printer by katzer to handle native printing cross-platform Android/iOS.

Is it safe to assume the plugin is at fault/causing the crashes? Last update for the plugin was over 8 months ago.

Full backtrace:

backtrace:

#00  pc 000000000006ca30  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)

#01  pc 0000000000069eb8  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+64)

#02  pc 0000000000024198  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+24)

#03  pc 000000000001c9b0  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+52)

#04  pc 0000000000435c2c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+352)

#05  pc 00000000000e524c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+1204)

#06  pc 00000000004c6c60  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art28InvokeProxyInvocationHandlerERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPKcP8_jobjectS5_RNSt3__16vectorI6jvalueNS6_9allocatorIS8_EEEE+2960)

#07  pc 00000000005520a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickProxyInvokeHandler+1040)

#08  pc 00000000000db0ac  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_proxy_invoke_handler+76)

#09  pc 0000000002cb0420  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.util.ArrayMap.indexOf+204)

#10  pc 0000000002cb0704  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.util.ArrayMap.indexOfKey+160)

#11  pc 0000000002cb16b4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.util.ArrayMap.remove+48)

#12  pc 0000000002a1f194  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.print.PrintManager.removePrintJobStateChangeListener+176)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Cordova CLI and cordova-android versions are you using? On what Android versions is this crash happening? Have you tried the Android emulators? Can you determine if this crash is specific for a certain Android version only, like 7.1?

I would assume that the crash is directly related to the plugin. You should post those logs at the [Issues](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer/issues) section of the plugin page, because he seems to be actively updateing his plugins.

Comment: Seems the error was due to 'android.print.PrintManager.removePrintJobStateChangeListener' and the cordova plugin had been updated to fix this but for some reason wasn't updating to the the latest version when updating the plugin from command line. Have made the necessary changes and submitted an update - hopefully this bug is squashed! Thanks for your reply.